# Javascript src Variable Not Detected by Script

Tags: javascript, variables, url, src

The script file and the jsfile reside together on an Apache homepage server.
In the head section of index.html we have

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="someurl/jsfile.js"></script/>
```

And in the scriptfile we refer to jsfile by

```
function init_disp() {array_len = jsfile.length...
```

Running the scriptfile with or without someurl produces an "'jsfile' is undefined" error. Is there a problem here, or if the server software is blocking the script, does it do it by nulling the variables?

Using IE11 with enhance protect and 64 bit enhance protect, 64 bit Java.
Edit: The entire scriptfile (not my own) is this:

```
    addEvent(window,"load",init_disp);
    addEvent(document,"click",show_init);
    // function to add an event listener
    function addEvent(o,e,f) {
    if (o.addEventListener) {
    o.addEventListener(e,f,false);
    return true;
    }
    else if (o.attachEvent) {
    return o.attachEvent("on"+e,f);
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
    }
    // integer "random()"
    function rand (n)
    {
    return (Math.floor( Math.random ()*n));
    }
    // BEGIN customization settings
    var char_pause = 60; // pause on each character, milliseconds
    var quote_pause = 8000; // pause to show complete quote, milliseconds
    // END customization settings
    var quoteindex;
    var quote,attribution;
    var pos;
    var box;
    var array_len;
    var quote_len,attrib_len;
    var interval = null;
    var busy;
    var cursor_span = "<span class=\"quotefont quotecursor\">";
    var hide_span = "<span class=\"quotefont hidecolor\">"
    var attr_div = "<p></p><div class=\"quotefont attrib\">";

    function init_disp() {
    array_len = jsfile.length;
    box = document.getElementById("quotebox");
    quoteindex = rand(array_len);
    show_init();
    }
    function show_init() {
    busy = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
    quote_array = jsfile[quoteindex].split("\t");
    quote = quote_array[0];
    attribution = quote_array[1];
    quote_len = quote.length;
    attrib_len = attribution.length;
    quoteindex = (quoteindex+1) % array_len;
    pos = 0;
    interval = setInterval('show_quote()',char_pause);
    }
    function show_quote() {
    pos++;
    if(!busy) {
    busy = true;
    if(pos <= quote_len) {
      box.innerHTML = quote.substring(0,pos) +
      cursor_span +
      quote.substring(pos,pos+1) +
      "</span>" +
      hide_span +
      quote.substring(pos+1) +
      "</span>";
    }
    busy = false;
    }
    if(pos > quote_len) {
    pos = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval('show_attr()',char_pause);
    }
    }
    function show_attr() {
    pos++;
    if(!busy) {
    busy = true;
    if(pos <= attrib_len) {
      var attr = attribution.substring(0,pos);
      box.innerHTML = quote + attr_div + attr + "</div>";
    }
    busy = false;
    }
    if(pos > attrib_len) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval('show_init()',quote_pause);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is javascript, not java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works as expected; or rather, that's not how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load a Javascript file using `<script>` tag, that file gets executed, not loaded as a Javascript object.

Comment: Yes, any luck with the undefined?

Comment: As per my answer, the result of `<script>` execution is not being set into `jsfile` variable, so it is undefined.

Comment: You just saw it? I can redo the question with his code if you like.

Comment: On that page I can only see some html code that executes JS files, no inline Javascript code. Anyway, if he is counting lines, I guess he is counting lines in a text area, not in a js file.

Comment: @LaurieStearn, yes please, add the code that works to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86629/discussion-between-laurie-stearn-and-danil-gaponov).

Comment: That's fine, appreciate anything you can come up with later then. Thanks

Comment: @LaurieStearn his `quotes.js` file starts with `quotes = [`, that is he writes an array of strings into global `quotes` variable. It is just a coincidence that this variable has the same name as the file.

Comment: Oh right. So how does the quoter.js know about the quotes.js file then? Has he left something out perhaps? I'll send him a PM

Comment: quotes.js initialiazes a global `quotes` variable that persists on the page.

Comment: Oh dear, that was not noted. Thanks David. Working now, no urls required at all. You are welcome to close it now as per Mathletics.